# Why var eva = function() {} does't work for addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I do not know why the code below does not work! But if I change `var eva = function(){alert("hello");}` to `function eva() {alert("hello");}`, it works.

```
var myForm = document.forms["form1"];

myForm.addEventListener("submit", eva);

var eva = function() {
alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: Why should that code work? You're using a variable you haven't defined yet.

Comment: Look up 'differences in variable hoisting between function expressions and function declarations.'

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the `eva` function via `addEventListener`, it's an undefined variable. Then, you set it to a function. Essentially, when you write it like you have:

```
var myForm = document.forms["form1"];

myForm.addEventListener("submit", eva);

var eva = function() {
alert("hello");
}
```

You're effectively writing this:

```
var myForm = document.forms["form1"];
var eva; // = undefined    

myForm.addEventListener("submit", eva);

eva = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

The declaration of the `var` gets [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), but not the assignment. By using a function declaration, `function eva() { ... }` gets similarly [hoisted](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) to the top of the scope and is a valid function when you pass it to `addEventListener`.

So, you have two options:

1. Move the var declaration *and* assignment above the call to `addEventListener`.
2. Use the function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`eva` is not defined at the point where you use it.

However, this does work:

```
var myForm = document.forms["form1"];

var eva = function() {
alert("hello");
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", eva);
```